# Delete Map with key in riak

Tags: php, riak

I am using riak php client and have datatype map. I want to delete entire map by key which is itemid. here is my code

```
        $location = new Location($itemID, $this->itemBucket);
        $map = (new \Command\Builder\FetchMap($this->riak))
        ->atLocation($location)
        ->build()
        ->execute()->getMap();

        (new \Command\Builder\UpdateMap($this->riak))
        ->removeMap($itemID)
        ->atLocation($location)
        ->withContext($map->getContext())
        ->build()
        ->execute();
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the KV key containing a map object and a map key containing a nested map.

This location will refer to `"http://riaknode:8098/buckets/$this->itemBucket/keys/$itemID"`

```
    $location = new Location($itemID, $this->itemBucket);
```

This retrieves the mapt object contained by the above bucket/key

```
    $map = (new \Command\Builder\FetchMap($this->riak))
    ->atLocation($location)
    ->build()
    ->execute()->getMap();
```

This attempts to remove the element with the key `$itemID` from the returned map object

```
    (new \Command\Builder\UpdateMap($this->riak))
    ->removeMap($itemID)
    ->atLocation($location)
    ->withContext($map->getContext())
    ->build()
    ->execute();
```

If you want to remove the entire map stored under that bucket/key, you probably need to use a `\Command\Builder\DeleteObject`